# Low volt LED signage ( two separate signs)

Tags: led

We are installing a sign in front of our building the top one says spine pro, and the bottom says accident and injury center. They are all 12 volt led and worked while on the ground. Now that it’s installed and wires are pulled through the wall we are having some issues. 110v to dc 12v transformer. 16 awg. The transformer is about a foot away from the sign itself. We want to power both signs from the single power. Each hooked up separately work fine. But when both hooked up the transformer blinks and acts as if there was a short. However if both are working separately how could a short be possible? This sign worked on the ground before installation so we know there is enough power. All contacts seem legitimate and stable. Let me know if you have any ideas! Thanks

Aaron[image]

Comment: that's typical behaviour of an over-loaded powersupply,  buy a stronger transformer or if there's110v handy connect both transformers to it and use both.

Answer (score 1):

### Insufficient Power

Considering the voltage and current was adequate for each sign but not both indicates your regulated supply is complaining from over curr over temp due to high current.

Start my specifying the rated Power (watts) for each string and then get a PS that is rated higher than  the sum of both at 12V.

Answer (score 0):

Each sign worked when powered independently, but not when powered together. How is it that you are detecting a short? Is it a direct indicator from the transformer LED?

Power converters have a maximum power output they are designed for. If your converter is rated for 20 W for example, and each of the signs requires 12 W, then each sign will work properly when it is connected to the converter alone. If you draw more power than the converter can supply, it usually has the effect of reducing the output voltage.

Look at buck converts such as this one...
[image]

Notice the capacitor in parallel with the load. This capacitor is what powers the load when the switching converter is in the off state. It is designed to provide power momentarily, usually in the microsecond range. But drawing more power (more current through two LED signs) from this capacitor than the converter is rated for will cause the voltage to drop to levels lower than the LED signs can accept for normal operation.

You will need either a second power converter, or a larger replacement for the current converter you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I’m mostly confused because on the ground before installation, the two into the one power converter worked fine. Both signs came on. All the letters included were meant for one power supply the one the manufacturer included. But now that it’s up on the wall, if we only hook up one at a time it’s working. But if we hook up both the power converter just blinks. Just weird that before they both worked together and now they only work separately.

Comment: How long are the wires you are using between the power converter and the signs, also what gauge? Only thing I can think of (if the signs draw high current) is that the voltage drop on the wire conductors is enough to drop below the input range the signs accept.

Comment: They are about 2 feet so I estimate a voltage drop to be .2 volts. 16awg copper, 2feet, 12.5 amps, 12v dc

Comment: But we did daisy chain the LEDs... possibly that adds extra distance to that calculation of voltage drop

Comment: Is there a datasheet or product link for the power converter and signs you are using?

Comment: Cant seem to find a sheet or link (China)

Comment: It reads, FX S 400W-12V

Comment: Ac input: 110/ 220V+/- 15% 50 Hz /   dc output: 12V 12.5amp

Comment: The power converter outputs 12 V 12.2 A? What is the FX S 400 W 12 V referring to? The same power converter?

Comment: I suspect your problem is with the power. Please clarify the power ratings of the power converter, and the power demands of the signs. Also, if possible actually measure the voltages and currents on the signs, both when hooked up independently and when connected together.

Comment: also the inductor powers the load while the switch is open. also. hs supply is probably not that layout. - probably isolating.